# How to split the screen into 2 rows in which 1st row takes no more than 50% (but can take less)

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can I design the ContentPage in Xamarin.Forms so that it's split in 2 sections: the upper one is a ListView that can have 1, 2 or 50 items to display, and the lower one, let it be a BoxView that should FillAndExpand to whatever available area is.

So, if the ListView has 1 or 2 items to display, it will take maybe up to 15% of the screen, whereas BoxView should have 85% available. If, on the other hand the ListView has 50 items to display, it should take no more than 50% of the screen and if necessary enable scrolling. Bottom line, BoxView should never be smaller than 50%.

Is that doable?

Comment: Please avoid putting tags in title when it is not necessary [Should I use tags in titles?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: I would use a grid with two rows, but you are going to need to dynamically calculate the size of the first row based on your ListView content - Forms is not going to be able to do it for you